# c function parameters order of evaluation

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing, operator-precedence

I understand that there are no guarantees regarding the order which the parameters of a function will be called, but, isn't it guaranteed that if there's a function call as parameter, that function will be called first?

I help students on the laboratory of an introductory subject on programming, and they were supposed to create a recursive factorial function which receives the n (for n!) and a pointer to an integer that will be used to count function calls and then they are supposed to print the results (n, n! and count).

Many were complaining that their use of pointers were wrong so I looked at the code and they were all like this:

```
int fat(int n,int *count)
{
    (*count)++;
    if(n>1)
    {
        return n * fat(n-1,count);
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n, count=0;
    do
    {
        printf("Write n for fat (n >= 0): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while(n<0);

    printf("Input: %d. Output: %d.\nFunction called %d times.\n\n", n, fat(n, &count), count);
    printf("%d times\n",count);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 the output is:

```
Write n for fat (n >= 0): 4
Input: 4. Output: 24.
Function called 0 times.

4 times
```

So, if fat was supposed to run first, the "Function called..." should print "Function called 4 times" instead of 0.

So, my question is:

Even though it's guaranteed that a function call in a parameter will run before the "receiving" one, it is still uncertain whether it runs before looking at parameters that aren't function calls?

Another strange thing is that this same code prints "Function called 4 times" on xcode...

Comment: Well, thanks everyone. I'd upvote the comments if I had reputation >= 15, but you guys helped a lot. Thanks. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it guaranteed that if there's a function call as parameter, that function will be called first?

No, that is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation of actual parameters is not defined. The fact that one of your parameters is the result of evaluating a function call changes nothing. The other parameters could be evaluated before the function is called.

With your example:

```
printf("Input: %d. Output: %d.\nFunction called %d times.\n\n", n, 
    fat(n, &count), count);
```

the call to `printf` is passed 4 parameters. These parameters can be evaluated in whatever order the compiler chooses.

Comment: I thought that if there was a function call that it would run before evaluating any other parameter.

So there's no guarantee even in this case. I'll make sure to teach them this. Thanks man!

Comment: But LLVM on xcode seems to be helping mac programmers, or it was some crazy coincidence. I'll borrow one to make some tests.

Answer (score 3):

> isn't it guaranteed that if there's a function call as parameter, that function will be called first?

It is guaranteed that in a call such as the following:

```
f(g(), h)
```

`g` will be called before `f` is called. However, there is no guarantee that `g` is called before `h` is evaluated.

Generally, if you care which of two things happens first, put them in separate statements. That way, you won't have to memorize sequenced-before relationships or wonder when side effects occur.

Comment: Better be safe. I'll tell them to run these type of calls separately. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, printf is given 4 parameters. Each of those parameters has to be evaluated before entering printf, but the order in which they are evaluated is not specified. Compilers take advantage of this to optimise code.

C99 §6.5.2.2p10:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual
>   arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is
>   unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Input: %d. Output: %d.\nFunction called %d times.\n\n", n, fat(n, &count), count);
```

In this code, `fat()` is guaranteed to be called before printf() is called, but there is no guarantee about the order in which `n`, `fat()`, and `count` are evaluated -- `count`'s value as an argument to `printf()` could be the value it had before `fat()` was called, or the value it has after.  Further, I think this is totally undefined behavior, in which case `count` could take on absolutely any other value as well.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such a guarantee neither in C nor in C++ (the exception is C#).  So arguments of a function call can be evaluated either from right to left (usually for most of compilers) or from left to right. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

It is obvious that  used by you compiler evaluates arguments from right to left. count is avaluated first so its value is 0. Then the compiler evaluates the call of function fat and at last it evaluates n.

To get the correct result you should  split the printf statement into two statements

```
int rez = fat(n, &count); 
printf("Input: %d. Output: %d.\nFunction called %d times.\n\n", n, rez, count);
```