# Precedence of Evaluation and Assignment operators in printf parameters

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k=35;
    int a=k==35;
    printf("%d %dn", k==35, k=50);
    printf("%d %dn", a,k=50);
    return 0;
}
```

In the first `printf` statement, why `k==35` evaluates to `0` ? I assume this may be because of the fact that `k=50` assignment happens before `k==35` evaluation. However, I do not understand why the `printf` parameters are not evaluated in order ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c function parameters order of evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600108/c-function-parameters-order-of-evaluation)

Comment: @RaymondChen in that example there is no undefined behaviour, however in this one there is

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as `printf("%d %d\n", k, k++);` which is [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529682/unexplained-behavior-of-printf-i-i-and-variants) although the existing answers leave a bit to be desired

Comment: @MattMcNabb For some reason, most order-of-evaluation answers get duped back to that one. To its credit, it opens with the answer: "I understand that there are no guarantees regarding the order which the parameters of a function will be called."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%d %dn", k==35, k=50);
```

It's unspecified whether `k=50` or `k==35` is evaluated first, so this code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation within `printf()` is not defined so this leads to undefined behavior.