# C program cannot show the output

Tags: c

My C program does not show the output.

My code in the C language:

```
int x = 0; // Installment
int y = 0  // Balance

for (i=1; i<=installment;i++)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", i, x=totalFee/installment, y = totalFee-(totalFee/instalment));
        }
```

Correct output:

```
Total fees: 300
Month  Installment  Balance
  1      100          200
  2      100          100
  3      100            0
```

My output:

```
Total fees: 300
Month  Installment  Balance
  1      100          200
  2      100          200
  3      100          200
```

This is just part of the code. Because this is the part where I have an issue. Other parts are fine.

Comment: If you program in C, why did you add the C++ tag?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Boy are we in sync. Just edited it too.

Comment: Maybe you should deduct from the current balance...

Comment: It is weird to expect different outputs with a loop that print always same values.... I mean `totalFee`, `installment` and `x` are constants inside the loop so....

Comment: And fyi, you can *not* assume the evaluation+assignment for `x` happens before `y` in your function call. [Order of parameter eval is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600108/c-function-parameters-order-of-evaluation).

Comment: `int y = 0` does not terminate with a semicolon.
`installment` is not defined.
`totalFee` is not defined.

Comment: If I change the for loop into the below:
  for (i=1; i<=installment;i++)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", i, x=totalFee/installment, y = totalFee-(totalFee/installment,));

        }

Comment: With the new edit, neither the question nor any of the posted answers make any sense. Voting to close this as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (i=1; i<=installment;i++)
{
    x = totalFee/installment;
    y = totalFee-x;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, x, y);
}
```

In C/C++, the compiler decides in which order it evaluates the parameters when a function is called. There is absolutely no guarantee that the order will be from first to last parameter. So most likely it evaluated `totalFee-x` before  `x = totalFee/installment` which is not what you expected.

See [Compilers and argument order of evaluation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c) or [Order of evaluation in C++ function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters) or even [function parameter evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566187/function-parameter-evaluation-order).
Specially, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9566538/3336423).

Now you updated your post and replaced by `y = totalFee-x` by `y = totalFee-(totalFee/instalment)`. This last one should work as `y` assignment does not rely on `x`. If it does not work for you, it's just that you are doing your operations the wrong way. Use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Bro,

Thanks for your reply. 
But the output still the same as the balance still cant deduct.

Comment: Also from what the asker says, he probably wants x = x * i inserted after the initialisation of x.

Comment: Actually I just wan my "y" to be deducted. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely related to order of evaluation of function parameters. You cannot know or assume that `x=totalFee/installment` is executed before `y = totalFee-x`. Also, it is generally bad practice to use assignment inside expressions.

Try to change your loop body to:

```
x = totalFee/installment;
y = totalFee-x;
printf("%d %d %d\n", i, x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don`t understand your loop

let`s step it.

First,
i = 1, x = 300/3 = 100, y = 300 - 100 = 200

Second,
i = 2, x= 300/3 = 100, y = 300 - 100 = 200

third,
i = 2, x= 300/3 = 100, y = 300 - 100 = 200

the x you make it 100

Comment: You can't assume that the loop gets executed this way.

Comment: OK.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The program for your required output

```
for (i=1; i<=installment;i++)
{
    x = totalFee/installment;
    y = totalFee-(x * i);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all help.. I really appreciate it. May God bless u all.