# Why does a function parameter later in an argument list have its side effects take place before an earlier one?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n2 = 11, n1 = 12;

int test(int n1, int n2)
{
    int r1, r2, r3;    
    r1 = n1 + n2; r3 = n1 - n2; r2 = n1 * n2;    
    return r1, r2, r3;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n1 = 11, n2 = 12;    
    printf(" %d ",  test(printf("Sunbeam Pune"), printf("Sunbeam Karad")));    
    printf("%d %d\n", n1, n2);    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Sunbeam KaradSunbeam Pune  -1 11 12
```

Why is "Sunbeam Karad" printed before "Sunbeam Pune" and why is there -1 in the output?

Comment: Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator Then read [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) to see what `printf` returns

Comment: And also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600108/c-function-parameters-order-of-evaluation

Comment: PSA: Don't "stack" multiple statements on one line. It's not worth the readability cost.

Comment: Bottom line - you have mixed together a bunch of different things while each of these is often confusing beginners. You should separate it into small simple examples demonstrating each aspect individually and try understanding one by one.

Comment: You might also find it helpful to add newlines to the strings you're printing to avoid line buffering issues.

Comment: When I learned C, the order of the inner printfs was unspecified. I'm told its defined now, but don't write code like this. It's bad in every language because it's hard to understand.

Comment: @Joshua Though even if it still wasn't defined now it would only affect the order of `pune` and `karad` printed, but not the number sequence afterwards...

Comment: Function arguments having side-effects is always going to be problematic. Either in terms of a language not specifying its behavior, or in terms of humans comprehending what's going on.

Comment: @Aconcagua, ...if the OP has multiple questions about distinct behaviors that contribute to code segment's output, they should be asked separately; otherwise, the question overall is too broad to be on-topic.

Comment: @Joshua Doesn't apply to function or operator arguments, as it [seems](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order), but instead, among others, to assignment (sequence point between right hand and left hand evaluation, or in C++ wording, right hand sequenced before left hand).

Answer (score 2):

> Why is "Sunbeam Karad" printed before "Sunbeam Pune"

**No particular reason** as far as the C language is concerned. The evaluations of different arguments in the same function call expression are not sequenced relative to each other.  They can be performed in either order.  The implementation does not even need to be consistent about the order.  Your particular implementation produces the ordering you observe for reasons of its own.

> and why is there -1 in the output?

**Because that is what your `test()` function returns.**  Supposing that the two `printf` calls serving as its arguments succeed -- which seems safe, given that you observe their output -- each returns the number of characters printed.  The other main consideration is the `return r1, r2, r3;` in `test()`.  That is an expression involving two uses of the comma operator (`,`), which evaluates its first operand, discards it, then evaluates its second operand to determine its own result.  I leave it to you to work out the details.

Note well that the commas in the argument list of a function call are not comma operators, and have no sequencing behavior, whereas comma operators do sequence the evaluations of their operands (left operand first).

Answer (score 1):

There are two key facts to understand the output you observed:

1. There's a sequence point in between the function execution and evaluation of the function arguments, but order of evaluation of the function arguments is unspecified (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order)). That means the compiler can freely decide in which order it evaluates them, and many compilers do so from right to left – obviously, too, the compiler *you* are using (actually that's quite natural as the most important [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) – cdecl, stdcall, X64, AMD64 – mandate placing function arguments onto the stack from right to left as well).
2. You need to understand the sequence (comma) operator:
   `expression, expression, ..., expression`
   It executes the individual expressions from left to right, discarding all their values but the last one, which gets the value of the entire expression. So `r1, r2, r3` calculates to simply `r3` – note that C doesn't allow multiple return values (which an ingenuous reader might have concluded from this code piece).
3. `printf` returns the number of bytes it has written, and as second string is longer by one character you get a difference of `-1`, which is what `r3` is calculated to: `r3 = n1 - n2`.

Side note: Any of the integers `n1` and `n2` aren't touched anywhere (other than on assignment); `test` has its own set of, they are *different* variables just equally named, same for `main`, and in both cases the global ones are hidden within the respective functions.

Be aware, too, that there's no way to access hidden variables as long as the hiding ones are still in scope.

Comment: Thanks Aconcagua for the explanation  and helping me out